# Across with NA values

Tags: r, tidyverse, across

I was trying to take the mean of some columns using across and there was an issue
making new different columns on for each column of the mean I used.
Is it working properly?

```
    library(tidyverse)
    cars %>% 
as_tibble() %>% 
add_case(speed = 11, dist = NA, .before = 1) %>% 
add_column(names = str_c("a",1:51)) %>% 
rename_with(.cols =  -names, ~str_c("one_",.x)) %>% 
group_by(names) %>% 
mutate(two = across(starts_with("one"), .fns = mean))
```

In the vignette it shows this example:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(c(x, starts_with("y"))), mean)
# ->
df %>% mutate(across(c(x, starts_with("y")), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I would expect that in every case with NA it would produce NA instead of another column.

Comment: Is this an answer? Because I haven't seen and difference.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I looking in the end to have a new column with name "two" in which I would have the mean of the other two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't necessarily see the use of `across` here if you want to take rowwise `mean` of two columns.

```
library(dplyr)
cars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  add_case(speed = 11, dist = NA, .before = 1) %>% 
  add_column(names = str_c("a",1:51)) %>% 
  rename_with(.cols =  -names, ~str_c("one_",.x)) %>% 
  mutate(two = rowMeans(select(., starts_with('one')), na.rm = TRUE))
```

You can use `rowwise` with `c_across` but it is going to be inefficient then `rowMeans`.

```
cars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  add_case(speed = 11, dist = NA, .before = 1) %>% 
  add_column(names = str_c("a",1:51)) %>% 
  rename_with(.cols =  -names, ~str_c("one_",.x)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(two = mean(c_across(starts_with('one')), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I would like to do the rowmean on several columns but different groups.
Better I guess rowMeans, that trying to complicate with across.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is an easier option. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I haven't thought about rowMean in the first place which makes everything easier. SHould I delete the question because it is a duplicate probably?

Comment: You should not delete the question if it is duplicate, mark it as duplicate question instead. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate